# C# Get Byte Array from HTTPResposeMessage

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpresponse, .net-5

I have an API that returns a PDF file as a byte array:

```
HttpResponseMessage fileResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(report) //here the byte array is >80000 in length
};
fileResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return fileResponse;
```

On the client, I have:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
    result = await client.GetAsync(getFileURL);
}
Byte[] bytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

This code worked until an upgrade to .Net 5.

Now bytes is only <350 in length. I have tried converting it from a base64 string as I have read in other solutions, but that throws an error saying it is not a valid base64 string:

```
string base = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
byte[] byte = Convert.FromBase64String(base);
```

Here's what base looks like after the replace, which the next line says is not a valid base64 string. Looks like json but no byte array:

```
{version:{major:1,minor:1,build:-1,revision:-1,majorRevision:-1,minorRevision:-1},content:{headers:[{key:Content-Type,value:[application/pdf]}]},statusCode:200,reasonPhrase:OK,headers:[],trailingHeaders:[],requestMessage:null,isSuccessStatusCode:true}
```

So any ideas on how to get the byte array out the response?

Comment: Looks like the default now is HTTP/2.  Not sure what is broken.  Need to do more research.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-5.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: `response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result` should be `result`? Does `fileResponse` contain all the bytes in your API? Where/how are you determining you have <350?

Comment: @mxmissile ya sorry that's a typo

Comment: See following : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#http-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I got to work was instead of having the API return an HttpResponseMessage, have it return the byte array directly.

Then in the client converting it from a base64 string gave me the correct byte array that I was able to write as the PDF.